# Cocos2d - Scaling a scene to fit to the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using the `CCTMXTiledMap` layer.

It doesn't fit the screen exactly.
Theres a pretty big border at the top of the screen.
How can I scale the scene to fit exactly the screen size with all of it's children?

I saw that you can use the camera:

```
[myLayer.camera setEyeX:0 eyeY:0 eyeZ:zoomValue];
```

But that is not recommended, and for some reason doesn't even work.
I change the value, but nothing happens. Except if I put the `eyeZ` value to `0`, then the layer disappears.

Comment: How about designing your tilemap so it fits the screen size perfectly? For example if you use tiles that are 40x40 points in size, it will fit the 480x320 resolution with no cut-off tiles.

Comment: This would very well be possible. But is this really the right approach? It doesn't seem to be.. I don't like "calculating" that stuff because of compatibility.